# Having trouble filling string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, matrix

My program is a DNA Sequence Alignment. It compares two DNA sequences by searching for a series of characters that are in the same order in all sequences.

I have hit a roadblock and would really appreciate some help. I need to fill my alignment matrix so it ends up looking something like this:

[image: OUTPUT]

This is just an example, the two DNA strings could be any size which I derive from a separate file but I've got all of that. I just need help actually putting it into the matrix.

So at first I was thinking about making a 2D char array but then I switched to a 2D string array since my DNA sequences are stored in two strings.

GUIDELINES ON FILLING THE MTX:

 All slots along the top row should be set to the gap penalty times their index, i.e. 0*gap, 1*gap, 2*gap…

 All slots along the left column should be set to the gap penalty times their index, i.e. 0*gap, 1*gap, 2*gap…

 Starting at the top left most empty slot and working left to right, top to bottom, each slot should be filled according to the following constraints:
   If the letter for each DNA string corresponding to the slot’s position are the same, then the slot’s value should be the diagonal up and left slot’s value plus the match score

 If the letter for each sequence corresponding to the slot’s position are not the same, then the slot’s value should be the max of:
   o The up slot’s value plus the gap penalty
   o The left slot’s value plus the gap penalty
   o The diagonal up and left slot’s value plus the mismatch penalty

Here is some code I have:

```
int match = 1;
int mismmatch = 7;
int gap = -1;

string seq1 = "GAATTCAGTA"; //DNA sequence 1: GAATTCAGTA
string seq2 = "GGATCGA"; //DNA sequence 2: GGATCGA

int DNA1Size = seq1.length();
int DNA2Size = seq2.length();

string mtx[DNA2Size][DNA1Size];

matrix[0][0] = " ";
matrix[0][1] = "-";
matrix[1][0] = "-";

for(int i = 2; i < DNA2Size; i++)
{
    mtx[i] = seq2.at(i);     //Hoping this would initialize the first row with sequence 2 
}

for(int z = 2; z < DNA1Size; z++)
{
    mtx[z] = seq1.at(z);    ////Hoping this would initialize the first column with sequence 1
}
```

So, I know this is wrong but its what Ive got so far. This is me attempting to initialize the first row and column with the designated letters and gaps/dashes. Also, the rest of the matrix is supposed to initialized by using the gap, match and mismatch but since I haven't even gotten this part, I haven't started on that yet. If anyone could help, I'd love you forever!

Comment: `string mtx[DNA2Size][DNA1Size];` is not valid C++, since `DNA2Size` and `DNA1Size` are not compile-time constants. Some compilers support "variable length arrays" at runtime as a vendor-specific extension. Do not rely on that. Use `std::vector` or `new[]` instead to dynamically allocate your variable-length arrays at runtime. That being said, your code still won't work the way you showed, because you are trying to assign individual `char` values to `string` array elements. Your first instinct to use a 2D `char` array was correct

Comment: Thanks! I actually had the string initialized but my program is so long I didn't include that part.

Comment: You have not adequately described the expected output of your program, nor the actual output.  Please refine your question based on the guidelines set out in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This approach should get you going:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using Matrix = vector<vector<string>>;

int main()
{
    string seq1 = "GAATTCAGTA"; //DNA sequence 1: GAATTCAGTA
    string seq2 = "GGATCGA"; //DNA sequence 2: GGATCGA

    int DNA1Size = seq1.length();
    int DNA2Size = seq2.length();
    const int numHdrCells = 2;

    Matrix matrix(DNA2Size + numHdrCells, vector<string>(DNA1Size + numHdrCells));
    matrix[0][0] = " ";
    matrix[0][1] = "-";
    matrix[1][0] = "-";

    for (int i = 0; i < DNA1Size; i++) {
        matrix[0][i + numHdrCells] = seq1.at(i);     //Hoping this would initialize the first row with sequence 1
    }

    for (int z = 0; z < DNA2Size; z++) {
        matrix[z + numHdrCells][0] = seq2.at(z);    ////Hoping this would initialize the first column with sequence 2
    }
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take in account that you need 2 more rows and columns than size of you sequences, if you want to store ' ' and '-' symbols at the beginning.

To fill first row in a matrix you keep index of row to 0 and change in loop index of column (cell). To fill column you do the opposite - keep index of column 0 and change index of row.
Example solution:

```
string seq1 = "GAATTCAGTA"; //DNA sequence 1: GAATTCAGTA 
string seq2 = "GGATCGA"; //DNA sequence 2: GGATCGA

int DNA1Size = seq1.length();
int DNA2Size = seq2.length();
int i, rows, columns;
rows = DNA2Size + 2;
columns = DNA1Size + 2;

char matrix[rows][columns]; //some compiler allow to define matrix this way

matrix[0][0] = ' ';
matrix[0][1] = '-';
matrix[1][0] = '-';

for (i=0; i<DNA2Size; i++)
  matrix[i+2][0] = seq2.at(i);  //filling first column

  for (i=0; i<DNA1Size; i++)
    matrix[0][i+2] = seq1.at(i); //filling first row
```

Comment: There are at least two problems with this example:

1. It will not compile, because the rows and columns are not constant values. And it is unlikely that in a fully functional applikcation they could be constant values, because the length of seq1 and seq2 would probably be variable inputs.

2. Declaring matrix as a char array won't work, because we know from the image provided that some elements will need to contain multi-character strings such as "-11".

Comment: 1. It depends on compiler. GNU GCC Compiler for example compiles this code, although the values of rows and colums are not constant. But ok, I agree, this is not universal solution. I was too lasy to add few lines to dynamically allocate memory with new[] constuction.
2. Some elements of the matrix need to contain values such as -10, -11... but this is numbers, not strings. So it is not problem to store it in char.

Comment: 1. If I had to use an array for some unknown reason, I would allocate it using std::make_unique, not new[]. But I think using a std:vector is a better approach.  
  
2. If the array must contain values, such as ' ', '-', 'A', 0, 4, -11, etc. I suppose you could represent all those using char, but it might get tricky overloading char as someones a character and sometimes a signed integer. That may or may not be better than using string. If an element ever needs to contain more than one character or an integer too large to fit in char, then you must use string.